# How to cast double to float pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers, casting

I'm trying to cast double to float pointer but I don't know the proper way to do it.

Here's my code

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    // insert code here...


    float *f;
    double d = 10;

    f = reinterpret_cast<float*>(&d);
    d = 20;

    std::cout << "RESULT : " << *f << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

And I get the following result.

```
RESULT : 0
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

How do I properly cast double to float pointer?

**ADD : The result I expect to get is 20**

Comment: You cannot do this. What problem are you _actually_ trying to resolve? Is this an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/)?

Comment: What do you expect to happen when you cast a pointer to a complex 64-bit representation (mantissa, exponent) to a pointer to a *different*, 32-bit representation and then interpret the memory pointed to after the new representation? Casting values is one thing, casting pointers... something else entirely.

Comment: You can just do: `*f = static_cast<float>(d);` or even `*f = d;` No need to cast the pointer.

Comment: It sucks that it's not possible.

Comment: @ZackLee: No it doesn't. It's really rather sensible.

Comment: What output did you expect?

Comment: @M.M I expect to get 20

Comment: That said, I don't understand the downvoting. This question is well asked, with a code snippet. Are we not allowed to ask good questions anymore?

Comment: Again, what are you trying to do? Why not do what the answers suggest?

Comment: @Bathsheba probably because it is viewed as too basic and lacks context

Comment: @PasserBy: And that is extremely subjective. The questions I asked my General Relativity professor at university were probably considered by him to be basic.

Comment: @Bathsheba That is different, I don't think SO aims to be a tutorial site

Comment: I also don't understand the close votes for "unclear what you're asking" reason. It's very clear what he's asking.

Comment: @MichaelWalz I voted for unclear what you're asking because I really don't know. Simply answering it's UB isn't helpful, but I don't know what will be, I don't know what OP is trying to do

Comment: @MichaelWalz The question already contains the correct answer to itself. It seems to me the real question is why the output differed from what was expected. Originally the question didn't even say what output was expected.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Consider:**

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cassert>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double d = 10;
    float f;
    assert( sizeof d == 8 );
    assert( sizeof f == 4 );

    unsigned char * d_ = (unsigned char *)&d;
    printf( "%hhx %hhx %hhx %hhx %hhx %hhx %hhx %hhx\n", d_[0], d_[1], d_[2], d_[3], d_[4], d_[5], d_[6], d_[7] );
}
```

This, at least on my machine, gives the following output:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 24 40
```

**Explanation:**

That is the internal representation of a `double` with value `10`.

By casting the `double *` to `float *`, you are only looking at the first four bytes of this -- `0 0 0 0`. Do you see *why* you are getting a `0` output when you dereference the pointer?

(Aside from, as others have pointed out, the dereferencing of the pointer being undefined behaviour due to breaking strict aliasing.)

**Solution:**

What you probably *want* is to cast the *value* of `d`:

```
static_cast<float>(d);
```

You can *then* store that value in an object of the correct type:

```
float f = static_cast<float>(d);
float * fp = &f;
```

Comment: @ZackLee: [IEEE Standard 754 Floating Point Numbers](http://steve.hollasch.net/cgindex/coding/ieeefloat.html) has a good explanation of the internal representation, in case you're interested.

Comment: Upvote to @M.M for pointing out the strict aliasing breakage.

Answer (score 4):

Your code for casting the pointer is correct.

The mistake is `*f`, which causes undefined behaviour by violating the strict aliasing rule.  You can not read or write through a pointer that has the wrong type for the object it points to. (with a small list of exceptions).

Answer (score 4):

The behaviour is *undefined*: the language offers no way of doing this. For example, `sizeof(float*)` does not have to be the same as `sizeof(double*)`. C++ aims to maximise flexibility.

You are allowed to cast the address of a `double` to a `const unsigned char*` pointer and read the memory that way.

Otherwise you need to resort to assembly, where at the CPU level, the distinction between a pointer to a type and an integral type is considerably blurred.

If you want to *convert* a `double` to a `float`, then write

```
double d = 10; float f = d;
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is a narrowing `static_cast`:

```
auto f = static_cast<float>(d);
float* pointer = &f;
```

The use of `reinterpret_cast` will fail, because it will not issue the compiler to change the bitwise representation of a `double` to that one of a `float`. It literally will reinterpret the double value as a float, yielding weird and undefined results as the representations differ. `static_cast` on the other side will take care for you that the representations are adjusted correctly, possibly truncating the least significant bits if necessary. After this, you can safely use the address of the float variable and access the value with a pointer.

Answer (score 1):

The behavior you want *can* be implemented in C++. Not via a raw pointer, though, but C++ allows user-defined types.

```
class double_as_float {
  double& d;
public:
  double_as_float(double& d) : d(d) { }
  float operator*() const { return static_cast<float>(d); }
};
```

Usage:

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {

    double d = 10;

    double_as_float f { d };
    d = 20;

    std::cout << "RESULT : " << *f << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```